# Elastic Beanstalk running multiple api's on different ports

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a Nodejs app that includes both an express api and a web socket api. The express app runs on port 3000 and the web socket api on port 3001. I have the entire node app running on an elastic beanstalk instance and want the express app to be accessed via the subdomain **api.example.com** and the web socket api via **ws.example.com**. How can I achieve this using route 53 and elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by running both api's on the same port using the http module!